# Can I use Apigee to make Facebook batch requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to execute a Facebook batch request, as described in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) from the [Apigee API console](https://apigee.com/console/facebook). However, there doesn't seem to be an appropriate resource drop down for batch requests; it's trying to force me into selecting a specific resource, and then insists on a parameter in its "template" tab which is not what I want.

Are FB batch requests supported in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, though the Facebook Console wasn't designed to make batch requests easy. You can try this:

1. Visit https://apigee.com/console/others
2. In the Resource box enter: https://graph.facebook.com
3. In the Query tab, create a parameter named "access_token" with the value of your facebook access token (because FB uses bearer tokens, you can cut and paste one from any valid OAuth request)
4. In the Body tab, enter the batch as a JSON string. Example below.

batch=[{"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me"},{"method": "GET", "relative_url": "me/friends?limit=50"}]

Hope that helps,

Marsh

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, it wasn't designed for this. Much appreciated.